# Error with "Get Started" on Oracle Express 11g

Tags: oracle10g, oracle11g

this is my first post so I will try to be as descriptive as possible. Please let me know if there is anything missing:

So I am trying to install Oracle Express 11g, after I download the zip file "OracleXE112_Win32" - I unzip it, and open Disk 1 then setup. I go through the entire installation process without any problems. However when I go to open "Get Started" I come across the following error:

"Windows cannot find 'http:/.127.0.0.1:%HTTPPORT%/apex/f?p=4950'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again. -- After googling this, I was told to change %HTTPPORT% to 8080.

If I do this when I click on "Get Started" the following error shows up:
"Firefox can' establish a connection to the server at 127.0.0.1:8080."

I need this to work, so that I can sooner or later connect this to my eclipse, so that I can start doing my homework for my Java Programming class. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you so much!

Answer (score 8):

I have found one solution for this problem. In order to explain my solution, I have used some aliases referring to my real parameters. These are:

```
[ME] = my user name
[MYHOST] = my current workstation hostname (netbios name as well)
[MYHOST.mycompany.com] = my worksation's fully qualified domain name
```

At the beginning I had the same situation as mentioned above: I was unable to connect to the apex service even after successful installation.

First I have used the tnsping oracle utility:

```
C:\Users\ME>tnsping MYHOST
```

This was the answer:

```
TNS Ping Utility for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
Copyright (c) 1997, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Used parameter files:
C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\admin\sqlnet.ora

Used HOSTNAME adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=))(ADDRESS=
(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=fe80::5d34:78a:5862:64%20)(PORT=1521))
(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=fe80::c27:54a4:1600:86a4%26)(PORT=1521))(ADDRESS=
(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=fe80::38ab:cdb4:dd77:7ed9%12)(PORT=1521))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)
(HOST=10.9.32.208)(PORT=1521))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.56.1)(PORT=1521))
(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.1.106)(PORT=1521)))

TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
```

You see above a lot of currently active different IP addresses. Only the most important 127.0.0.1 is missing. I work on notebook so the network is "almost always" changing (WLAN, 3G, HSDPA, Ethernet etc.) only the localhost is fixed. And that was the real case of the trouble. (When I was working at the office environment connected to the office network it was also working.)

When I was in this situation I also started to use the lsnrctl oracle utility.
I have seen the following:

```
LSNRCTL> status
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   /oraclexe/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/server\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\diag\tnslsnr\MYHOST\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1ipc)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=MYHOST.mycompany.com)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

You can see that the service for the apex at 8080 port is missing !!!
I have tried also the normal ping which worked perfectly:

C:\Users\ME>ping MYHOST.mycompany.com

The result was:

```
MYHOST.mycompany.com [fe80::c27:54a4:1600:86a4%26] ping
response fe80::c27:54a4:1600:86a4%26: time<10 ms
...
```

You can realize the IPv6 address also exists in my tnsping trial as well.

So I have decided to define MYHOST in my local hosts file directly:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost MYHOST MYHOST.mycompany.com
```

Testing now with ping:

```
C:\Users\ME>ping MYHOST
```

And the answer:

```
MYHOST.mycompany.com [127.0.0.1] ping:
response 127.0.0.1: byte=32 time<10 ms. TTL=128
 ...
```

At this point I have restarted (stopped and started again) the both running Oracle services (just for sure):

```
OracleServiceXE
OracleXETNSListener
```

And look the miracle:

```
C:\Users\ME>lsnrctl

LSNRCTL for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production

LSNRCTL> status
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   /oraclexe/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/server\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\diag\tnslsnr\MYHOST\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1ipc)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=MYHOST.mycompany.com)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=MYHOST.mycompany.com)(PORT=8080))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "XEXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "xe" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
LSNRCTL>
```

You can see the important line with PORT=8080 and service XE instance.
So I am happy the getting started URL is working again.

Comment: This post woke up a stone dead Oracle 11g XE HTTP listener on my Win7 system. Just added the indicated line to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts and the HTTP service worked, even without restarting the Oracle services. Many Thanx Miklos, you saved my day!

Answer (score 2):

What browser are you using?  I experienced the same issue with Chrome.  Download firefox, Right click the "Get Started With Oracle Database 11g Express Edition" icon and change the "opens with" option to firefox.

Comment: Thank you! :) Just going to HTML file via path in shortcut and dragging the file in chrome or firefox solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution:

You need to directly tell where your http port is. To do so; open up the folder where your Oracle is stored and navigate to server folder( in my case C:\Oracle\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server) in that folder right click to Get_Started file and choose properties. There you can hand type your http port which is usually 8080 in my case: ....127.0.0.1:8080/apex/f?p=4950

The problem should be solved.

Hope this helps you get through it..

Pinar U.S.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on the "Get Started" icon and click on the properties and select General tab. Click on change button and select other browser installed in your system other than the current one . after setting this up, you'll be able to open the panel.

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced the same problem for this go to start-> all programs -> Oracle Database 11g Express Edition and right click on get started and click open file location and drag and drop the "Get_Started" to your browser

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution. Right click on icon of "Get Started With Oracle Database 11g Express Edition", then "properties". Then click "General tab" and then you will see option "change", click on that and then select your browser, click "apply" and "ok". And then start the Database again.

Answer (score 0):

Drag and drop get started link into browser address bar worked great for me, I tried EVERYTHING else, adding port to hosts, changing port in properties etc. nothing worked, until I dragged and dropped... So damn simple, wish I did that hours ago

Comment: It actually is an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is partially correct buddy. You need to match the entries in the file:

C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\ADMIN\listener.ora

(the entries with the --> mark)

```
:

LISTENER =

  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =

    (DESCRIPTION =

      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))

-->   (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))

-->   (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = myserver.company.com)(PORT = 1521))

    )

  )

:
```

With the entries in the file:

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

(the entries with the --> mark)

```
:

--> 127.0.0.1   localhost

--> 1.2.3.4     myserver    myserver.company.com

:
```

Finally, under Administrator account do:

C:> lsnrctl stop

C:> lsnrctl start

Solved. No need for changing name, no drag & drop either.

Comment: No need for bad words either :)